# boolean logic: demorgan's theorem, NAND gates

Tags: boolean-logic, demorgans-law

I am trying to build a circuit for the following portion of my boolean equation:

```
(!A + !B + !C(!D + !E)
```

Expanding this, we of course get:

```
(!A + !B + !C!d + !C!E)
```

With demorgan's theorem, I thought we could reduce it to

```
(ABCDCE)!
```

Which I though could be reduced to: 
ABCDE because A * A = A.

However, when I put in A B C D E into a NAND gate, I do not get the results that I need. Why is this? Where did I go wrong in my logic?

EDIT: so @Leandro Caniglia explained the problem:

```
!A + !B + !C + !D + !E != !A + !B + !C!D + !C!E
```

So is the furthest I could reduce it:
`(AB)! + !C(DE)!` ?

Is there any way else that could simplify it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `(!A + !B + !C!D + !C!E)` is not equal to `(ABCDCE)!` because the latter is `(!A + !B + !C + !D + !C + !E)` according to the (generalized form of) De Morgan theorem and `!C!D` is not `!C + !D` (the same happens with `!C!E`).

Answer (score 0):

A 5-variable Karnaugh Veitch map

[image]

leads to

```
!B + !A + !C!E + !C!D
```

That can be transformed to

```
!(AB) + !C!(DE)
```